# arcpy.da.InsertCursor() Fails with SDE But Works with Local FGDB

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor, data-access

I am trying to use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()` to insert rows to an SDE **table** but no rows were added and without any error message. I tried the same code with an exact replica table in a local FGDB and it worked fine. The code is simple:

```
workspace = r"Database Connections\SDE.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(sde_table, ["Date_"])
cursor.insertRow(["10/21/2020"])
```

I also tried to use `arcpy.InsertCursor()` and it works well in both SDE and local FGDB. Is there anything missing for getting `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()` to work in SDE?

RDBMS: SQL Server 2012

Python: 2.7

SDE: 10.6.1

Comment: I haven't ever had a DA InsertCursor fail silently, so more details are necessary:  Which RDBMS? What version? What version of ArcPy? What version of geodatabase? What are the exact column names? Have you tried using `with` so that the session is committed without an explicit `del cursor`?

Comment: @Vince, thanks for replying. I added the info in the question. I only have one column name right now bacause it's a test. I tried ```with``` but no luck.

Comment: As presented, I wonder it that's a legal date (I always use ISO "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"), but in a cursor you need to bind the right type (unless you're passing a string to a string field named "Date_").  The commit won't happen without the `del cursor` and `edit` directives.

Comment: OK, so I need to put in ```2020-10-21 00:00:00```, ```del cursor```, and  ```edit.stopOperation()``` and ```edit.stopEditing(True)```?

Comment: @Vince Thank you for your help. It's now working after adding ```del cursor```, ```edit.stopOperation()``` and ```edit.stopEditing(True)```. What a silly mistake. Also, ```"10/20/2020"``` works fine. Seems no need to put in the ISO date. But I don't quite understand why the code used to work in local FGDB without these closing commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
import arcpy
import os

fc = r'Database Connections\Connection to sde.sde\table'
workspace = os.path.dirname(fc)


edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)


edit.startEditing(False, True)


edit.startOperation()


with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ('field1', 'field2')) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow(("string1", "string2"))



edit.stopOperation()


edit.stopEditing(True)
```

The above code should work for you. just replace the SDE location, field1 and field2 and finally the string1 and string2

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried your suggestion but no luck. I also directly pasted the full SDE and table paths to it and still not working.

Comment: Thank you. I added the missing ```edit.stopOperation()``` and ```edit.stopEditing(True)``` and it's working.

Comment: I use the above code it worked for me. Happy to hear that it also worked for you.

Comment: Yes thanks for reminding me of the stop operation and stop editing - that's where the problems are. Nothing to do with the path or fields.